# Fail to install RCall - Julia package

Tags: r, package, julia, rcall

Following [RCall's documentation](http://juliainterop.github.io/RCall.jl/stable/installation.html), I ran `Pkg.add("RCall")` which looked to be working. Then, running `using RCall` gave:

```
WARNING: could not import StatsModels.Formula into RCall
ERROR: LoadError: RCall not properly installed. Please run Pkg.build("RCall")
#... few lines later
ERROR: Failed to precompile RCall [6f49c342-dc21-5d91-9882-a32aef131414] to C:\Users\jke4\.julia\compiled\v1.1\RCall\8GFyb.ji.
```

That's why I ran `Pkg.build("RCall")`:

```
┌ Error: Error building `RCall`:
│ ERROR: LoadError: R cannot be found. Set the "R_HOME" environment variable to re-run Pkg.build("RCall").
```

I believe, accordingly to RCall's documentation that I have to do [a custom installation](http://juliainterop.github.io/RCall.jl/stable/installation.html#Customizing-the-R-installation-1), but why can't am I able to simply install by `Pkg.add("RCall")` like it's suppose to be done?

> `RCall.jl` can simply be installed with
>
> `Pkg.add("RCall")`

Note:

- Julia version is `1.1.0`.
- `using Conda` does work.
- There is no R version installed in my Windows computer
- I do understand what is my error message and how I can deal with it. My question is why do I have it whereas I wasn't suppose to, quoting RCall's documentation:

> RCall.jl will automatically install R for you using Conda if it doesn't detect that you have R 3.4.0 or later installed already.

## Update

Alright, I've done what @Cameron Bieganek suggests: `pkg> pin StatsModels@0.5`
And it seems to work for a moment. However, after doing `] up`, accordingly with the issue I had in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841854/how-to-change-the-precision-of-ticks-in-julia-plot).

`using RCall` now gives:

```
ERROR: LoadError: RCall not properly installed. Please run Pkg.build("RCall")
```

and `Pkg.build("RCall")`:

```
┌ Error: Error building `RCall`:
│ ERROR: LoadError: IOError: stat: invalid argument (EINVAL)
```

This time I can't get what's the error.

## GitHub

Please note that this question is also referenced on [GitHub RCall.jl](https://github.com/JuliaInterop/RCall.jl/issues/318).

Comment: So maybe Julia is unable to find Conda?

Comment: Hum, yes maybe, how can I check that? I mention in the question that `using Conda` returns no errors. Perhaps Julia should have tell me that it doesn't find Conda? That'll be more understandable than the current erros? Thank you for your comments :)

Comment: Have you reviewed the hits to an SO search on `[julia] [conda]`? The first couple I looked at appeared to have potentially useful information. I'm not a julia or conda user but the impression I formed from the couple that I read suggests that conda is expected to have been installed in a dependent portion of the julia directory tree. Perhaps you installed them separately?

Comment: I ran into the same issue today. I think it's related to the very recent update of StatsModels.jl. Perhaps RCall.jl doesn't have the right restrictions on the version of StatsModels.jl in order to avoid trying to use v0.6 of StatsModels? Try fixing StatsModels.jl to v0.5 using something like `pkg> add StatsModels@0.5` in the package manager.

Comment: Or maybe `pkg> pin StatsModels@0.5`.

Comment: @CameronBieganek Alright, thanks that worked for a moment. I've updated my question because I still face an issue.