# How to change the precision of ticks in julia plot

Tags: plot, julia

I'm plotting in julia for the first time and have installed the Juno IDE. I'm plotting with Plots.jl and every time I plot, the y-axis tics have lots of decimals.

I've tried multiple backends, like GR, Plotly, PlotlyJS, but none have changed the behavior I'm seeing.

This is the code I have currently producing my results:

```
    using Plots
    gr()
    x = 1:10; y = rand(10)
    p = plot(x,y)
```

And the figure that's output:
https://github.com/bojohnson02/Random/blob/master/fig.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a temporary bug caused by some changes to Showoff, the package that Plots uses to create the axis ticks. It should be fixed already, so updating your packages should work (`]up`). If it doesn't work yet, and you're in a hurry, installing `master` of the two packages should do the trick (`] add Plots#master` followed by `] add Showoff#master`).

Comment: Looks like it's working now, thanks for the heads up.